# Is there a standard definition of a hill?

Tags: terminology

I think we can all agree that these are hills:

[image]

<sup>Image from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Chocolate_Hills.jpg)</sup>

They're kinda gentle, not too tall, and altogether nice-looking. But it's always bugged me that I can't come up with an objective definition for the word. Is that little bump in my lawn a hill? It's gentle, not too tall, and altogether nice looking. But I still wouldn't call it a hill.

Is there a widely accepted definition for 'hill'?

Comment: That's pretty nice karsted terrain.  (Appears to be an excellent example of cockpit karst.) Where is that?

Comment: It's of Chocolate Hills in the Philippines, @Joe. I grabbed it from [Wikipedia Commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Chocolate_Hills.jpg), probably should have attributed it. Done now.

Comment: I think this is more or less a duplicate of http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/104/is-there-a-standard-definition-of-the-term-mountain - the question in both is "what's the difference between a mountain and a hill".

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson: "what's the standard definition" and "what's your definition" are two very different questions.

Comment: @naught Never mind, retracted the close vote. It seems like this is more of a scientific definition (quantitative, not qualitative). | Undo: That looks more like a small mountain to me! :P